# Método que encuentra concurrencias consecutivas de un numero dado en Java

Tags: java

Necesito un método que recibe un array de elementos `enteros(Interger[] array)` y un elemento entero `(Interger elem)` y devuelve el numero máximo de concurrencias consecutivas de elem.

Esto es lo que haría el método:

```
conConsElem([],2) --> 0
conConsElem([1],4) --> 0
conConsElem([1,8,3],8) --> 1
conConsElem([1,4,3,4,4,3],4) --> 2
conConsElem([1,9,9,9,3],9) --> 3
conConsElem([1,7,1,7,1,7],7) --> 1
```

Comment: Deberías explicar mas que es lo que pides

Comment: Me dan un array. Lo que me piden es que mire el numero maximo de concurrencias seguidas que hay de un numero, ejemplo: en el array 1,6,6,7,8,6   me piden que de el numero maximo de veces que el numero 6 se repite seguidas.Vemos que sale 3 veces: ...6,6... y ..6...  Hay dos 6 consecutivos y uno solo, con lo cual la respuesta seria 2, porque es el maximo.

Comment: Posible duplicado de esta pregunta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/196949/numeros-repetidos-en-un-array-list-devolviendo-un-el-valor-minimo-y-un-valor-tru

Answer (score 0):

Prueba lo siguiente:

```
private int conConsElem(array, num)
{
    int maximo = 0; // consecutivo de apariciones a retornar
    int contador = 0; // contador de consecutivo
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) 
    {
        if(array[i] == num) // si coincide se aumenta el contador
            contador++;
        else
        {
            if(maximo < contador) // sino se compara el contador y el max
                maximo = contador;
            contador = 0; // se reinicia el contador
        }
    }
    return maximo;
}
```