# Numeros repetidos en un array list devolviendo un el valor minimo y un valor true o false

Tags: java

Escribe una función o método que detecte si en un arreglo un número se repite, al menos cierta cantidad de veces. La función debe recibir el arreglo, el número que se quiere detectar y la cantidad de veces mínimas que debe aparecer.

**Ejemplo:**

> Para arreglo = [4, 5, 2, 4, 5, 9, 9, 4, 4]

```
contiene(arreglo, 4, 5) // Regresa false;
contiene(arreglo, 4, 4) // Regresa true;
contiene(arreglo, 4, 3) // Regresa true;
contiene(arreglo, 9, 2) // Regresa true;
```

**Este es el código de lo que he intentado:**

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] array = {1, 2, 2, 3, 6, 4, 4, 4, 9, 5, 6, 5, 9, 2};
    list = new int[array.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      int count = 0;
      for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
        if (array[i] == array[j]) {
          count++;
          if (numero(array[i])) {
            list[i] = array[i]; 
          } 
        } 
      } 
      if (list[i] != 0) {
        System.out.println(list[i] + " it has been found " + count + " times"); 
      } 
    } 
  }

public class DuplicatedDataInArray { 
   static int[] list; 
   static boolean numero(int num) { 
     for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
       if (list[i] == num) {
         return false; 
       } 
     } 
     return true; 
   } 
}
```

Comment: No es muy difícil de hacer, pero el chiste es que hagas el intento por lo menos.

Comment: Este es mi código, hasta ahí bien, la última parte es donde me atoré.

Comment: Donde esta el código? solo veo el llamado a la función. Agrega como estructuras la función.

Comment: package duplicateddatainarray;

public class DuplicatedDataInArray {

    static int[] list;

    static boolean numero(int num) {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            if (list[i] == num) {
                return false;
                
            }
            
        }
        return true;
    }

Comment: public static void main(String[] args) {
      
        int[] array = {1, 2, 2, 3, 6, 4, 4, 4, 9, 5, 6, 5, 9, 2};
        list = new int[array.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            int count = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
                if (array[i] == array[j]) {
                    count++;
                    if (numero(array[i])) {
                        list[i] = array[i];
                    }

                }

            }

Comment: if (list[i] != 0) {
            System.out.println(list[i] + " it has been found " + count + " times");
        } 
        }
    }

Answer (score 0):

Amigo, lo que no estabas haciendo era instanciar la clase que tiene la variable y el método que necesitas en el `MAIN`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  int[] array = {1, 2, 2, 3, 6, 4, 4, 4, 9, 5, 6, 5, 9, 2};
  DuplicatedDataInArray.list = new int[array.length];
  for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
      if (array[i] == array[j]) {
        count++;
        if (DuplicatedDataInArray.numero(array[i])) {
          DuplicatedDataInArray.list[i] = array[i];
        }
      }
    }
    if (DuplicatedDataInArray.list[i] != 0) {
      System.out.println(DuplicatedDataInArray.list[i] + " it has been found " + count + " times");
    }
  }
}

public class DuplicatedDataInArray { 
   static int[] list; 
   static boolean numero(int num) { 
     for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
       if (list[i] == num) {
         return false; 
       } 
     } 
     return true; 
   } 
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la observación.